# How to mount / after running "apt-get remove php5-curl"?

Tags: boot, apt, data-recovery, curl

While trying to tear down a Drupal dev environment, I ran

```
sudo apt-get remove php5-curl
```

It started removing all kinds of packages, like the browser, among other things. I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when I saw what it was doing but the damage was done I guess, because now it hangs at boot. I get "the disk drive at [wherever] is not ready or not present" where [wherever] is various drives starting with the crypt swap, but also including / in recovery mode.

It says to `press S to skip mounting or M to recover manually`, but neither gets a response. If I wait a really long time it progresses to a screen that says only, `Checking battery state... OK`. Then it hangs there.

What have I done? How do I fix it?

Upon trying to run a bootable 11.10 Ubuntu disk and trying to recover or repair the following errors started streaming from the machine:

[image]

A memtest revealed the following:

[image]

Does this mean the memory was bad all along? Did I somehow damage my RAM by removing packages? Is that even possible?

Comment: Sorry, there are a couple of typos. Thanks for catching then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bad memory. You cannot possibly damage RAM with software.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. I'm relieved to know it's not my fault at least :-/